# Why is part of the HTML email appearing as text in email client?

Tags: php, html, email, codeigniter

I am trying to send HTML emails with Codeigniter's [email class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html). This is how I am doing it:

```
    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'a@a.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'password',
        'mailtype'  => 'html', 
        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
    );
    
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->from('b@b.com', 'Me');
    $this->email->to($email); 
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($html);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n"); 

    if($this->email->send()){
        return true;   
    }else{    
        return false;
    }
```

However, when I view the email in Gmail or outlook, I see bunch of HTML appearing as text at the top of the email and the rest of the email is displayed normally.

[**Here**](http://pastebin.com/LP5nLtTY) is the HTML I am sending, its a template that I found to test with. Lines 1 to 19 appear as normal text and is not rendered.

[**This is**](http://img811.imageshack.us/img811/5435/ep4e06467d315f3outlook2.png) how the email looks.

Why is this the case?

Comment: I just thought of something. Could it be a GMail issue as I am sending through them? If so, how do I overcome this?

Comment: @Alex - what do you mean? I have set the `mailtype` to `html`.

Comment: @Abs - How is the content of `$html` created?

Comment: @abs It could maybe be an issue in gmail, maybe. Have you tried sending it via your server or a different email service?

Comment: @Francois - at the moment its a literal string that I pass in from a file. @JackMcE - It might be GMail but hopefully it isn't as I really need it to work with GMail, I don't have another option to be honest.

Comment: @Abs - Can you add `echo $this->email->print_debugger();` after the send, run it again, copy the result, obfuscate anything you don't want us to see and paste it here (or on [http://pastebin.com/](http://pastebin.com/))?

Comment: @Francois - there were quite a few `pre` and `br` tags in the debugging output. I removed those as I figured this is codeigniter trying to format it properly. Here is the output: http://pastebin.com/wyi79x9t

Comment: The above email was a very simple one. I used this as the contents of the email: http://pastebin.com/0kExaGbJ - it looks like it hasn't converted the html tags properly to html entities?

Comment: @Abs - It looks like the content of your `$html` variable has been put `htmlentities` or some other function. The information you pasted shows "&gt;html" when it should have been "<html" for example. Can you post the code that read the content of the file and put in into the `$html` variable?

Comment: @Abs - Just to clarify, you **don't** want to convert to html entities.

Comment: @Francois - I think you might be right. I used a `html_entity_decode` and the email has appeared fine now. I'll have to trace back to what caused this but you are right, if you can add your answer so that I can select it, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a summary of our conversation in the question's comments, the problem appears to be the content of the `$html` variable. The variable contains entity encoded HTML. Running it through `html_entity_decode` solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you Francois for sticking with me and helping me!

Answer (score 1):

HTML code not rendered seems to be the header of your template. Maybe Gmail will display only the code found inside the tag `body`, since Gmail is a web application, so it's displayed in a webpage already containing a header and a body (`<html><head><body>`).

Comment: I have viewed this same email in outlook and it also has the same problem. But it might be GMail sending it in an incorrect way.