# How to transform HTML tags into a real text when displaying in email client?

Tags: java, javascript, html

When I click a button, an email client pops up through `javascript`. Which should have prepopulated data stored in form of `HTML` tags from database.

Now, in my email client I don't want the HTML tags to appear, but I want the real English data with HTML formatting to appear; such as for example:

> Hello User,
>
> You are invited to join the conference.
>
> ***Please dial***   **12345**.  // <-- here is the HTML formatting
>
> Thank you.

Here is the [similar question related to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480315/why-is-part-of-the-html-email-appearing-as-text-in-email-client).

Answer (score 0):

I've searched the questions and found:

```
    function strip(html)
{
   var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   return tmp.textContent||tmp.innerText;
}
```

might help

Comment: myString.replace(/<.*?>/g, '');

Comment: Thanks. But, How to retain the HTML formatting like **bold**/*italic*/color?